# Текст убегает наверх

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, что бы рамочка с подписью фотографии появлялась на самой фотографии снизу?
ставлю position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; и рамка уплывает верх или вниз

```
<div class="content">

        <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c417427/v417427364/9650/VwYBzLxpZ6I.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="text"><a href="">Никитка в осеннем лесу</a></div>
</div>

.text{
    display: none;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;    
    padding: 20px;
    font: 14px/20px Tahoma;
}

.text a{    
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;            
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.content{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.content img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;  
    border: 4px solid #ccc;
}

.content:hover .text{
    display: block; 
    width: 260px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 4px solid #ccc; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так? http://jsfiddle.net/Q3A5h/3/